# Why I call this function 8 times, all results are from last time? In C

Tags: c, function, loops, call

This function is to convert strings represent binary to strings represent hex

```
char *tohex(char bnyin[32]) {

static char hexout[8];

int i=0;
int j=0;

for (i=0;i<8;i++){

    char txt[4];
    char hex;

    txt[0]  =   bnyin[i*4+0];
    txt[1]  =   bnyin[i*4+1];
    txt[2]  =   bnyin[i*4+2];
    txt[3]  =   bnyin[i*4+3];

    switch (atoi(txt)) {
        case    0:      hex = '0';  break;
        case    1:      hex = '1';  break;
        case   10:      hex = '2';  break;
        case   11:      hex = '3';  break;
        case  100:      hex = '4';  break;
        case  101:      hex = '5';  break;
        case  110:      hex = '6';  break;
        case  111:      hex = '7';  break;
        case 1000:      hex = '8';  break;
        case 1001:      hex = '9';  break;
        case 1010:      hex = 'a';  break;
        case 1011:      hex = 'b';  break;
        case 1100:      hex = 'c';  break;
        case 1101:      hex = 'd';  break;
        case 1110:      hex = 'e';  break;
        case 1111:      hex = 'f';  break;
    }
    hexout[i]   =   hex;
}
return hexout;
}
```

Main function calls the tohex function 8 times

```
int main (int argc, char**argv)
{
char *dl_hex[8];
char dl_bny[8][32];

for (i=0;i<8;i++) {
    dl_hex[i] = tohex(dl_bny[i]);
 }
}

for (i=0;i<8;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<8;j++){
        printf("%c",*(dl_hex[i]+j));
    }
        printf("\n");
}
```

After printed out all dl_hex, all results are the same with dl_hex[7], if I change to loop number to 6 times, all result are dl_hex[5], seems that no matter how many times I call the tohex function, all result will go for the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You return a static buffer, then it is the same for all calls and will then contains the last produced value.

You can (for example) simply copy the returned result each time you call `tohex` :

```
char dl_hex[8][9];

...

strcpy(dl_hex[i], tohex(dl_bny[i]));
```

Beware that your code if wrong in some places: `dl_bny` not initialized, strings must contains a final 0 so length should be 33...

Comment: strcpy might not work as the the contents of the char array doesn't seem to be '\0' terminated.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks the answer and it works great! Though the dl_bny is initialized somewhere else but what you mentioned did resolve my another question about '\0' terminator! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to a static buffer `hexout` from the function `tohex`. The contents of the static buffer `hexout` keeps changing during each iteration. Since, you are basically, storing the pointer to `hexout`. All the slots of `dl_hex` will be containing the same pointer (to hexout) and hence will contain the same value which is be the value obtained during the last run.

The best way for you would be to copy the values.

Change the main function of the code as below:

```
int main (int argc, char**argv)
{
char dl_hex[8][8];
char dl_bny[8][32];

for (i=0;i<8;i++) {
    strncpy(dl_hex[i],tohex(dl_bny[i]), 8);
 }
}

for (i=0;i<8;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<8;j++){
        printf("%c",*(dl_hex[i]+j));
    }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation! I tried strncpy then I got the correct results. I was wondering, for the first iteration, why not the first slot takes the first pointer immediately and then goes to the second iteration? For the case I have, It seems like the compiler calls the function 8 times at first, and then assign those 8 results to the 8 slots?